# Suggested GIT repo for product customization for each customer

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a core product that I wish to customize for every customer. Customers may demand new features or they would like to customize existing core feature. If there's a bug in core, I would like to deploy it for all the customers. If I believe a feature that I added for customer may also help other customers, I should be able to add that feature to the core product. What should be suggested GIT workflow for this requirement?.

Comment: A single repo, using feature flags to turn on features for customers, instead of trying to solve this problem with version control tools.

Comment: It's not just about turning a feature on or off. It's about customizing the existing workflow of the core product itself for each customer. I think about providing a admin interface to define the workflow rather than hard-coding it.

Comment: You'd be entering a world of pain. Taking @EdwardThomson's suggestion would enable you to develop a feature for one customer and sell it to many. It'd also avoid integration bugs which will be your primary pain point here.

Comment: @SenG - I understand, I'm just saying don't make an architectural problem a version control problem for therein lies madness.